# i want to run a job on specific node,but first runs on built-in node and after that it runs on the selected node

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

```
public void perform(Run<?, ?> run, FilePath workspace, EnvVars env, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    String selectedNodeName = getNodeName();
    Node selectedNode = Jenkins.get().getNode(selectedNodeName);
    String currentBuildNode = Computer.currentComputer().getName();
    if (selectedNodeName.equals(currentBuildNode)) {
        listener.getLogger().println("Build is already running on the selected node: " + selectedNodeName);
        // launcher.launch().cmds("echo", "Hello from " + selectedNodeName).join();
    } else {
        // Node selectedNode = Jenkins.get().getNode(selectedNodeName);

        if (selectedNode != null) {
            AbstractProject<?, ?> project = (AbstractProject<?, ?>) run.getParent();
            project.setAssignedNode(selectedNode);
            project.scheduleBuild2(0);
            listener.getLogger().println("Selected Node: " + selectedNodeName);
            launcher.launch().cmds("echo", "Hello from " + selectedNodeName).join();
        } else {
            listener.getLogger().println("Node Not Found: " + selectedNodeName);
        }
    }
}
```

and also it triggers the "Restrict where this project run" feature i dont know why?

i am creating a plugin for selecting a node to run a job on that node ,but it first runs on the built-in node and after it triggers the "Resstrict where this project can run",why it is happening like that?